# create multiple columns at once based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Create the lists for each column
nrows = 5
a = [[random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)] for i in range(nrows)]
b = [[random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)] for i in range(nrows)]
c = [[random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)] for i in range(nrows)]
idx = [random.randint(0, 3) for i in range(nrows)]

# Create the pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'idx': idx})
```

I want to create 3 more columns, `a_des`, `b_des`, `c_des`, by extracting, for each row, the values of `a`, `b`, `c` corresponding to the value of `idx` in that row. I could do this with 3 separate `apply` statements, but it's ugly (code duplication), and the more columns I need to update, the more I need to duplicate code. Is it possible to generate all three columns `a_des`, `b_des`, `c_des` with a single `apply` statement?

**EDIT**: sorry all, I made a mistake. Lists are of different length for different rows. I don't have time to fix this today, but I'll definitely do it tomorrow.

Comment: show your current `apply` approach

Comment: @DeltaIV. Please avoid changing your question because you already have 5 answers. Accept (or not) an answer for your actual question, then create a new one. Otherwise, other users may not understand why the answers are off topic and may vote down. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with a *dict/listcomp* & *[unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/)* :

```
out = (df.assign(**{f"{col}_des": [e[i] for (e,i) in zip(df[col], df["idx"])]
                    for col in df.columns[:-1]})) #or `for col in ["a", "b", "c"]`
```

Output :

```
            a           b            c  idx  a_des  b_des  c_des
0   [1, 9, 7]  [10, 7, 9]    [9, 9, 4]    1      9      7      9
1  [2, 10, 3]   [5, 8, 4]    [7, 0, 0]    1     10      8      0
2   [2, 8, 7]   [0, 8, 7]    [2, 9, 5]    0      2      0      2
3   [1, 2, 8]   [5, 5, 6]  [7, 10, 10]    1      2      5     10
4  [10, 0, 9]   [2, 0, 7]    [6, 6, 7]    1      0      0      6
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized I made a mistake in my question. I'll fix it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

a = [[random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)] for i in range(nrows)]
b = [[random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)] for i in range(nrows)]
c = [[random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)] for i in range(nrows)]
idx = [random.randint(0, 2) for i in range(nrows)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'idx': idx})

# Solution:
cols = ["a", "b", "c"] 
idx_col = "idx"

out = df.apply(lambda row: row[cols].str[row[idx_col]].add_suffix("_des"), axis=1)
```

Results:

```
>>> df
            a          b          c  idx
0   [4, 1, 2]  [1, 2, 9]  [8, 1, 5]    2
1   [6, 6, 1]  [4, 2, 5]  [4, 7, 1]    0
2   [8, 1, 7]  [7, 1, 1]  [9, 4, 1]    1
3  [6, 10, 4]  [6, 3, 0]  [6, 3, 1]    0
4  [10, 3, 5]  [4, 0, 3]  [6, 3, 7]    2
>>> out
   a_des  b_des  c_des
0      2      9      5
1      6      4      4
2      1      1      4
3      6      6      6
4      5      3      7
```

Also worth noting is that you could do this in a vectorial way if you had, for instance, a 3D numpy array, which you could consider.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I made a mistake in my question. I'll fix it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

For list of different length:

```
def extract_index(df):
    col = df.columns[0]
    return (df.explode(col).assign(g=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
              .query('idx == g')[col].rename(f'{col}_des'))

out = pd.concat([extract_index(df[[col, 'idx']])
                for col in df.drop(columns='idx')], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  a_des b_des c_des
0     4   NaN     6
1     2     5   NaN
2     3     7     0
3     1     7     4
4   NaN   NaN     8


>>> df
              a             b             c  idx
0  [3, 2, 4, 8]           [3]  [2, 1, 6, 3]    2
1  [1, 7, 2, 2]  [4, 0, 3, 5]        [0, 3]    3
2     [0, 3, 2]        [7, 7]  [7, 0, 3, 5]    1
3        [4, 1]        [9, 7]     [0, 4, 6]    1
4        [3, 8]           [1]  [9, 2, 9, 8]    3
```

---

IIUC, you can use `explode`:

```
>>> (df.explode(['a', 'b', 'c']).assign(g=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
       .query('idx == g').drop(columns=['idx', 'g']).add_suffix('_des'))

  a_des b_des c_des
0     9     0     6
1     6     6     0
3     7     4     9
4     1     3     5
```

Step by step:

```
>>> out = df.explode(['a', 'b', 'c'])
   a   b   c  idx
0  9   4   2    1
0  9   0   6    1
0  5   5  10    1
1  6   5   1    1
1  6   6   0    1
1  6  10   4    1
2  9   1   9    3
2  7   2   3    3
2  2   3   9    3
3  1   9   7    1
3  7   4   9    1
3  4   6   8    1
4  9   4   7    1
4  1   3   5    1
4  9   5  10    1

>>> out = out.assign(g=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
   a   b   c  idx  g
0  9   4   2    1  0
0  9   0   6    1  1
0  5   5  10    1  2
1  6   5   1    1  0
1  6   6   0    1  1
1  6  10   4    1  2
2  9   1   9    3  0
2  7   2   3    3  1
2  2   3   9    3  2
3  1   9   7    1  0
3  7   4   9    1  1
3  4   6   8    1  2
4  9   4   7    1  0
4  1   3   5    1  1
4  9   5  10    1  2

>>> out = out.query('idx == g').drop(columns=['idx', 'g']).add_suffix('_des')
  a_des b_des c_des
0     9     0     6
1     6     6     0
3     7     4     9
4     1     3     5
```

You can use `pd.concat` to merge both `df` and `out`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, out], axis=1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized I made a mistake in my question (I used ChatGPT to help my write my **question**, and that's the result ). I'll fix it tomorrow. BTW, I think your solution may be the only one that will work regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a **function** that returns the value corresponding to `idx` and then use `apply()`:

```
def ret_idx(x):
    x.a = x.a[x.idx]
    x.b = x.b[x.idx]
    x.c = x.c[x.idx]
    return x[['a', 'b', 'c']]

df[['a_des', 'b_des', 'c_des']] = df.apply(ret_idx, axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
            a           b          c  idx  a_des  b_des  c_des
0   [6, 5, 0]   [3, 5, 1]  [4, 9, 4]    2      0      1      4
1   [4, 2, 1]   [0, 4, 2]  [7, 0, 6]    2      1      2      6
2   [7, 7, 2]  [10, 6, 0]  [5, 1, 8]    2      2      0      8
3  [2, 5, 10]   [4, 2, 1]  [4, 1, 6]    0      2      4      4
4   [4, 9, 1]  [4, 5, 10]  [9, 9, 7]    1      9      5      9
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized I made a mistake in my question. I'll fix it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

If all your lists have the same length, use a 3D numpy array:

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.array(df[cols].to_numpy().tolist())
                     [np.arange(len(df)), :, df['idx']],
                    columns=cols
                    ).add_suffix('_des')
       )
```

Output:

```
            a            b           c  idx  a_des  b_des  c_des
0  [9, 2, 10]    [8, 7, 7]   [6, 4, 5]    2     10      7      5
1   [3, 4, 7]  [4, 10, 10]  [8, 10, 3]    1      4     10     10
2  [10, 8, 8]    [1, 4, 6]   [1, 0, 5]    2      8      6      5
3  [2, 10, 9]    [4, 8, 7]   [4, 3, 1]    2      9      7      1
4  [8, 5, 10]   [0, 9, 10]  [5, 1, 10]    0      8      0      5
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in writing the question. They're not all the same length. I don't have time to fix today, but I'll do tomorrow.